# Git commit difference between branches to master

Tags: git

I have two branches master and production.
production contains stable version of my program.
master has some features which i dont want to be in master.

In order to do it, i want to commit to master difference between
master and production.

```
git diff master production
```

the output of this command I want to commit to master, how can I do it?

Comment: Is there any reason you are averse to using `git merge` or a merge request?

Comment: Do you want to make (the tip commit of) `master` have the same *contents* as (the tip commit of) `production`? That is, every file should be exactly identical, whether you `git checkout master` or `git checkout production`? That's the literal outcome of what you're suggesting; and if that *is* what you want, there are two different ways to do this, depending on what you want remembered. But that's very rarely what people actually *want*.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
git diff dev_branch main > difference.patch
git checkout main
git apply difference.patch
```